# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bibliometrix’ in loadNamespace(j <-....: there is no package called ‘vctrs’

Tags: r

I had problem when I install bibliomatrix on my mac.
The problem is

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bibliometrix’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘vctrs’
```

I had install ‘vctrs’, and make sure it works.

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
```

Still the error same.

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘bibliometrix’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘vctrs’
```

Anyone please help. Thank you in advance

Comment: What was the output when you tried to install `vctrs`? What is your version of R? Do you have RTools installed?

Comment: The warning you got when trying to install `vctrs` clearly indicates that the installation failed, therefore there is no package with this name. However `bibliomatrix` apparently needs it to be loaded. You would need to find out (from the error messages during installation attempt of `vctrs`, just as Phil pointed out) _why_ the installation failed...